In Qt, how to prevent the transparent property of the parent window from affecting the child windows
I am using Qt/C++ for program development.
I used setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); to achieve the transparency of the window.
However, the backgrounds of all child windows have also become transparent.
I want the background of one of the child windows to be opaque, but other child windows to inherit this property.
How can I isolate the influence of this attribute of the parent window on it?
setStyleSheet(); does not work.

setStyleSheet() should work, as long as it's properly used, but if you don't show us how you used it, we cannot tell you what may be wrong with it. Please provide a proper [mre].

If setStyleSheet() isnt working, The only way seems to be this, Make the child window seperately. You can do this by not telling the child window its parent window, This way Qt will treat the child window as its own separate parent window and therefore, It will not apply transparency to it.
Example of making a seperate top level child window:
childWindow = new ChildWindow(); // Note that i am not specifying its parent

For PyQt5:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Class for child window
class ChildWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Call setGeometry method
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        # Call setWindowTitle method
        self.setWindowTitle("Child Window")

         # Add some widgets
        self.button = QPushButton('Child Button.', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 30)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.child_window = ChildWindow()
        self.child_window.show()

        self.button = QPushButton('Open Child Window', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

